# Tableau Server API to generate PDF is failing after generating 20-30 pdf using TSC(Tableau Server Client) package

Tags: tableau-api, tsc

I have been using Tableau Server Client package to login and generate PDFs.
However it is working fine for first few minutes and generates the PDFs but later it fails with below error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/test/conda/condapub/test/lib/python3.10/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1713, in feed
self.parser.Parse(data, False)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 8

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/sam/code/export_pdf_1.py", line 70, in 
workbook = tableau_server.workbooks.get_by_id(df.loc[i,'wk_d'])
File "/test/conda/condapub/sam/envs/tune/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tableauserverclient/server/endpoint/endpoint.py", lin
e 292, in wrapper
return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/test/conda/condapub/sam/envs/tune/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tableauserverclient/server/endpoint/workbooks_endpoin
t.py", line 88, in get_by_id
return WorkbookItem.from_response(server_response.content, self.parent_srv.namespace)[0]
File "/test/conda/condapub/sam/envs/tune/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tableauserverclient/models/workbook_item.py", line 29
4, in from_response
parsed_response = fromstring(resp)
File "/test/conda/condapub/sam/envs/tune/lib/python3.10/site-packages/defusedxml/common.py", line 126, in fromstring
parser.feed(text)
File "/test/conda/condapub/sam/envs/tune/lib/python3.10/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1715, in feed
self._raiseerror(v)
File "/test/conda/condapub/sam/envs/tune/lib/python3.10/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1622, in _raiseerror
raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 8

This is what I tried below :

```
tableau_token = TSC.PersonalAccessTokenAuth(TOKEN_NAME,TOKEN,SITE)
tableau_server = TSC.Server('https://sam.sa.com/', use_server_version= True, http_options=.   {"verify": False})
```

tableau_server.auth.sign_in(tableau_token)

```
with tableau_server.auth.sign_in(tableau_token):
    df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Wk_nm','wk_d'])
    for wb in TSC.Pager(tableau_server.workbooks):
            if wb.project_name == "ABC":
                df.loc[len(df)]= [wb.name,wb.id]
                for i in range(len(df)):
                    workbook = tableau_server.workbooks.get_by_id(df.loc[i,'wk_d'])
                    print(workbook)
                    pdf_req_option = TSC.PDFRequestOptions(page_type=TSC.PDFRequestOptions.PageType.Legal, orientation=TSC.PDFRequestOptions.Orientation.Landscape)


                    tableau_server.workbooks.populate_pdf(workbook, pdf_req_option)
                    file_nm= df.loc[i,'Wk_nm']
                    with open('./sam/export/pdf/'+file_nm+'.pdf', 'wb') as v:
                                v.write(workbook.pdf)
```

Comment: This could be an XML character encoding issue; [this post](https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D58b0000BAHv5fCQD/id-like-help-resolving-an-intermittent-problem-using-tableau-server-client-api-when-calling-serverauthsignin-xmletreeelementtreeparseerror-mismatched-tag-line-40-column-133) covers a multitude of debugging processes.